# Documents.Add in VBA is crashing Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, crash, office365

I have written a vba(word) add-in that I share with quite a few others. With Office 365 being more pervasive, I am starting to get 'crash' reports that I never got before. In debugging, I have found that the Documents.Add call is the culprit. When that line is encountered, it either crashes the program (Word restarts) or the new document is added, but no code after that line is processed (it totally jumps out of the program, but at least doesn't crash). Easily and consistently duplicable.

I created a bit of a workaround, but it's really not a good one. It's:
SendKeys "^n"

This only sometimes works.

Anyone have a better solution? Will Microsoft see this complaint?

Roy Lasris

Comment: Please provide a complete "Sub" that replicates the problem so that others can test it. Also explain what you mean by "add-in" and how the macro is called/executed. And no, Microsoft will probably not see this, here.

Comment: Even something as simple as this exhibits the behavior on the two machines that have reported the problem. Both machines Office 2016 Professional:

Sub AddNewDoc()
Documents.Add
End Sub

It doesn't matter if this code in in the normal.dotm or a separate add-in placed in the StartUp folder.

Comment: In StackOverflow you should use the [edit] link to put additional information (especially code) into the original question. This is apparently a problem on only some machines, so "easily and consistently duplicable" is not true in a general sense... Have they tried to repair the Office installation on those machines? Have they been sending the crash information in to Microsoft? Have you tried deleting Normal.dotm (a corrupted copy is often cause for a crash) so that Word generates a fresh copy? Do they have any other add-ins installed or anti-virus software that could be interfering?